# php artisan storage:link doesn't create link

Tags: laravel

I am working on a laravel project which i want to move to production.

Now, created a new folder in the root directory called core and moved all files from the root directory into the 'core' folder.

Now here is my new folder structure

```
project
|-core
  |-every other folders and files
|-public
  |-every other asset files
```

After doing this an updated the path in index.php , the website works well, but the storage images are not loading, it an error that the path was found.

Now, in the public folder, I deleted the storage link and and run `php artisan storage:link` , I get this return

```
php artisan storage:link
The system cannot find the path specified.

   INFO  The [C:\Users\user2\Desktop\project\core\public\storage] link has been connected to [C:\Users\user2\Desktop\project\core\storage\app/public].
```

But when i go to `public`, no storage folder link is created.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this problem, this is how I eventually solved it,

go to `config/filesystems.php`  and replace this

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

with this;

```
'links' => [
        '../public/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

Comment: better to not mess with the standard folder structure since now you have to have special deployment process for this site.  Better to upload all the files as they exist in development and then create a symlink that makes /core/public look like /public

Comment: That’s not a problem, I’ve made a custom installer for the project, created a custom public path.